# vsFTPd with Freeradius authentication

Tags: vsftpd, radius, freeradius

**EDIT:**

**Ok I actually missed out a log in Syslog, I was hopign it would appear in auth.log or vsftpd.log, but a crucial message was in Syslog:
Failed looking up IP address for RADIUS server [2001 (errcode=9)**

**No matter in what format I type the IPv6 address (tried with [] brackets, without them, and using alias in /etc/hosts) in the pam_radius_auth.conf, it won't take it. Seems like the pam module is not compatible with IPv6? :(**

I have two servers, one server running vsFTPd and second server running Freeradius. Both of them are IPv6only.

I am trying to use vsFTPd with pam_radius_auth module to authenticate via my radius server, but for some reason I am unable to make it work. Freeradius server should be configured properly, I can authenticate via terminal like this:

```
radtest -6 user pass 2001:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::129 0 radiussecret
```

Also my other webserver can authenticate via my radius server.

For some reason, it seems liek vsFTPd is not using the right pam module, I don't have any debug message that he attempts to connect to my radius server, or if I remove it from /etc/pam_radius_auth.conf completely, that it cannot find a server to connect to.

Here are my configs:

**/etc/vsftpd.conf**

```
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
pam_service_name=ftp
```

**/etc/pam.d/vsftpd**

```
auth       sufficient  pam_radius_auth.so
account    sufficient  pam_radius_auth.so
```

**/etc/pam_radius_auth.conf**

```
radiusserver radiussecret 10
```

And in /etc/hosts I mapped the radiusserver to its ip address:

```
2001:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::129 radiusserver.auth radiusserver
```

Now when on the FTP server I try to connect with the credentials user:pass, I get the following error:

```
ftp localhost
Connected to localhost.
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)
Name (localhost:student): user
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
530 Login incorrect.
Login failed.
```

In /var/log/auth.log:

```
 ubuntu vsftpd: pam_unix(ftp:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ftp ruser=user rhost=::1  user=user
```

and /var/log/vsftpd.log

```
CONNECT: Client "::1"
[user] FAIL LOGIN: Client "::1"
```

What is going on? Why is vsFTPd not even trying to connect to my radius server? :(
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In `/etc/vsftpd.conf` you have:

```
pam_service_name=ftp
```

I think that tells PAM to look for configuration for this service in `/etc/pam.d/ftp`, rather than `/etc/pam.d/vsftpd`.

If `/etc/pam.d/ftp` does not exist, `/etc/pam.d/other` will get used instead.

Comment: I was trying various variations of

pam_service_name=ftp
pam_service_name=vsftp
pam_service_name=vsftpd

but none really seems to fix my problem. Eventually I left it at ftp, according to https://askubuntu.com/questions/413677/vsftpd-530-login-incorrect

Because when I use "vsftpd", there is nothing showing up in /var/log/auth.log